# If $X_{n+1}$ is a martingale subject to $Y_0,\ldots,Y_n$, then is it a martingale with respect to $Y_0^2,\ldots,Y_n^2$?

Tags: probability, self-study, random-variable, stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation

I don't have a very solid foundation in measure theory, and this always seems a bit confusing to me so I would appreciate any help.

We are given 
$
E \left( X_{n+1} | Y_0,\ldots,Y_n \right) = X_n.
$
Prove or disprove
$
E \left( X_{n+1} | Y_0^2,\ldots,Y_n^2 \right) = X_n
$

I am thinking that if $F=\sigma \left(Y_0,\ldots,Y_n \right)$ and
$G=\sigma \left(Y_0^2,\ldots,Y_n^2 \right)$, I need to prove that F = G? Is this correct?

Then I can do something like this:
$
E \left( X_{n+1} | G \right) = E \left( E \left( X_{n+1} | F \right) | G \right) = E \left( X_{n+1} | F \right) = X_{n+1}
$.

Also is $E \left( X_{n+1}^2 | G \right) = X_n^2$ (a martingale) given
$
E \left( X_{n+1} | Y_0,\ldots,Y_n \right) = X_n.
$

Comment: Some intuition: In going from $Y_k$ to $Y_k^2$, do you lose any information? If so, about what? Now, consider the example of $X_n$ being a simple random walk. Is it a martingale with respect to $\sigma(X_0,\ldots,X_{n-1})$? What about $\sigma(X_0^2,\ldots,X_{n-1}^2)$?

Comment: Intuitively yes I would say you lose information. $g (x) = x^2$ is not one-to-one (ie it has 2 values on the domain for each range element). We know that if we are given $Y_0 = k_0, \ldots, Y_n= k_n$, we can get X_n. However, give $Y_0^2 = m_0, \ldots, Y_n^2= m_n$, we cannot derive $Y_0$ as it is not one-to-one. So therefore we cannot get $X_n$. I think this is the answer to the first part.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: $F=G$ is probably not what you want, not least because it's not true.  You do want the law of iterated expectations, though, that much you have right.  Something about sub sigma algebras . . .

Comment: For part 2, does $\text{E}f(x) = f(\text{E}x)$ in general?  Also consider the case of a simple random walk on the integers which is currently located at 0.

Answer (score 3):

> Prove or disprove
>   $
> E \left( X_{n+1} | Y_0^2,\ldots,Y_n^2 \right) = X_n
> $
>
> I am thinking that if $F=\sigma \left(Y_0,\ldots,Y_n \right)$ and
>   $G=\sigma \left(Y_0^2,\ldots,Y_n^2 \right)$, I need to prove that F = G? Is this correct?

Actually, $G\subseteq F$ and the inclusion can be strict.

> Then I can do something like this: $E \left( X_{n+1} | G \right) = E \left( E \left( X_{n+1} | F \right) | G \right) = E \left( X_{n+1} | F \right) = X_{n+1}
> $.

The third equality is wrong. When $G\subseteq F$, $E \left( E \left( X_{n+1} | F \right) | G \right)= E \left( X_{n+1} | G \right) \ne E \left( X_{n+1} | F \right)$ in general hence this proves nothing.

Here is a counterexample to the statement you are trying to show: if $(Y_k)$ is an i.i.d. Bernoulli sequence, then $Y_n^2=1$ almost surely hence $E \left( X_{n+1} | Y_0^2,\ldots,Y_n^2 \right) = E(X_{n+1})\ne X_n$ in general.

> Also is $E \left( X_{n+1}^2 | G \right) = X_n^2$ (a martingale) given
>   $
> E \left( X_{n+1} | Y_0,\ldots,Y_n \right) = X_n.
> $

No. Actually, by convexity, $E \left( X_{n+1}^2 | G \right) \geqslant E \left( X_{n+1}| G \right)^2= X_n^2$ and the equality holds if and only if $X_{n+1}$ is measurable with respect to $G$.

Answer (score -1):

$G \subseteq F$

If we know $Y_0, Y_1, ...$, then we know $Y_0^2, Y_1^2, ...$ The converse is not true.

$E[X|G] = E[E[X|F]|G]$, but $E[X|F] \ne E[E[X|G]|F]$.

$E[X|G] = E[E[X|F]|G]$ allows you to prove the converse of your conjecture is true.